# Maybe monad and a list

Tags: haskell, monads

Ok, so I am trying to learn how to use monads, starting out with maybe. I've come up with an example that I can't figure out how to apply it to in a nice way, so I was hoping someone else could:

I have a list containing a bunch of values. Depending on these values, my function should return the list itself, or a Nothing. In other words, I want to do a sort of filter, but with the consequence of a hit being the function failing.

The only way I can think of is to use a filter, then comparing the size of the list I get back to zero. Is there a better way?

Comment: You can use the [`any`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.12.0.0/docs/Data-List.html#v:any) function to see if the filtered list would have been empty. Idiomatically I think it makes more sense to just return the empty list, though.

Comment: The `Maybe` monad is for computations that may return zero or one value, while the list monad is for ones which can produce any number, from zero upwards. So `Maybe` is kind of a more limited sort of list, with at most one element. I don't see the need to combine them - just use lists.

Comment: @RobinZigmond Perhaps, but that depends on whether the OP wants the two kinds of emptiness to mean different things -- that is, `Just []` might mean "the computation succeeded by default because there were no values to test", while `Nothing` would mean some value led to a failure. On the other hand, if the OP wanted their function to produce `Nothing` when given an empty list, collapsing the layers would make sense.

Comment: That's exactly it duplode.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This looks like a good fit for [`traverse`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.12.0.0/docs/Data-Traversable.html#v:traverse):

```
traverse :: (Traversable t, Applicative f) => (a -> f b) -> t a -> f (t b)
```

That's a bit of a mouthful, so let's specialise it to your use case, with lists and `Maybe`:

```
GHCi> :set -XTypeApplications
GHCi> :t traverse @[] @Maybe
traverse @[] @Maybe :: (a -> Maybe b) -> [a] -> Maybe [b]
```

It works like this: you give it an `a -> Maybe b` function, which is applied to all elements of the list, just like `fmap` does. The twist is that the `Maybe b` values are then combined in a way that only gives you a modified list if there aren't any `Nothing`s; otherwise, the overall result is `Nothing`. That fits your requirements like a glove:

```
noneOrNothing :: (a -> Bool) -> [a] -> Maybe [a]
noneOrNothing p = traverse (\x -> if p x then Nothing else Just x)
```

(`allOrNothing` would have been a more euphonic name, but then I'd have to flip the test with respect to your description.)

There are a lot of things we might discuss about the `Traversable` and `Applicative` classes. For now, I will talk a bit more about `Applicative`, in case you haven't met it yet. `Applicative` is a superclass of `Monad` with two essential methods: `pure`, which is the same thing as `return`, and `(<*>)`, which is not entirely unlike `(>>=)` but crucially different from it. For the `Maybe` example...

```
GHCi> :t (>>=) @Maybe
(>>=) @Maybe :: Maybe a -> (a -> Maybe b) -> Maybe b
GHCi> :t (<*>) @Maybe
(<*>) @Maybe :: Maybe (a -> b) -> Maybe a -> Maybe b
```

... we can describe the difference like this: in `mx >>= f`, if `mx` is a `Just`-value, `(>>=)` reaches inside of it to apply `f` and produce a result, which, depending on what was inside `mx`, will turn out to be a `Just`-value or a `Nothing`. In `mf <*> mx`, though, if `mf` and `mx` are `Just`-values you are guaranteed to get a `Just` value, which will hold the result of applying the function from `mf` to the value from `mx`. (By the way: what will happen if `mf` or `mx` are `Nothing`?)

`traverse` involves `Applicative` because the combining of values I mentioned at the beginning (which, in your example, turns a number of `Maybe a` values into a `Maybe [a]`) is done using `(<*>)`. As your question was originally about monads, it is worth noting that it is possible to define `traverse` using `Monad` rather than `Applicative`. This variation goes by the name `mapM`:

```
mapM :: (Traversable t, Monad m) => (a -> m b) -> t a -> m (t b)
```

We prefer `traverse` to `mapM` because it is more general -- as mentioned above, `Applicative` is a superclass of `Monad`.

On a closing note, your intuition about this being "a sort of filter" makes a lot of sense. In particular, one way to think about `Maybe a` is that it is what you get when you pick booleans and attach values of type `a` to `True`. From that vantage point, `(<*>)` works as an `&&` for these weird booleans, which combines the attached values if you happen to supply two of them (cf. [DarthFennec's suggestion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53217914/maybe-monad-and-a-list/53219044#comment93323688_53217914) of an implementation using [`any`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.12.0.0/docs/Data-List.html#v:any)). Once you get used to `Traversable`, you might enjoy having a look at [the `Filterable` and `Witherable` classes](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/witherable-0.2/docs/Data-Witherable.html), which play with this relationship between `Maybe` and `Bool`.

Answer (score 1):

duplode's answer is a good one, but I think it is also helpful to learn to operate within a monad in a more basic way. It can be a challenge to learn every little monad-general function, and see how they could fit together to solve a specific problem. So, here's a DIY solution that shows how to use do notation and recursion, tools which can help you with any monadic question.

```
forbid :: (a -> Bool) -> [a] -> Maybe [a]
forbid _ [] = Just []
forbid p (x:xs) = if p x
  then Nothing
  else do
    remainder <- forbid p xs
    Just (x : remainder)
```

Compare this to an implementation of `remove`, the opposite of `filter`:

```
remove :: (a -> Bool) -> [a] -> [a]
remove _ [] = []
remove p (x:xs) = if p x
  then remove p xs
  else
    let remainder = remove p xs
    in x : remainder
```

The structure is the same, with just a couple differences: what you want to do when the predicate returns true, and how you get access to the value returned by the recursive call. For `remove`, the returned value is a list, and so you can just `let`-bind it and cons to it. With `forbid`, the returned value is only *maybe* a list, and so you need to use `<-` to bind to that monadic value. If the return value was Nothing, bind will short-circuit the computation and return Nothing; if it was Just a list, the `do` block will continue, and cons a value to the front of that list. Then you wrap it back up in a Just.

Comment: Nice answer. I would have liked to add a more step-by-step solution like this one, but then my answer would have grown too long and meandering.